# Spring Data Cassandra Counter update

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

In the spring data documentation, it says:

CassandraTemplate is the place to look for accessing functionality such as incrementing counters or ad-hoc CRUD operations.

I am trying to update a counter using the CassandraTemplate in spring-data-cassandra, but the documentation on this subject is very sparse. Is there a good example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use custom @Query to update the counter value.

For example, supposing you have some repository:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends CassandraRepository<SomeEntity> {

@Query("update some_table SET counter=counter+1 WHERE value1 = ?0 AND value2= ?1;")
Object updateCounterValue(String value1, String value2);}
```

Of course you can also parametrize the value being updated.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use the query as follows?

```@Query("update " + TABLE_NAME + " SET counter=counter+1 WHERE value1 = ?0 AND value2= ?1;")```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found any good example neither, but from the source of CassandraTemplate/CqlTempleate, code should look like:

```
Update updateOp = QueryBuilder.update(cassandraOperations.getTableName(MyMapped.class).toCql());
        updateOp.with(QueryBuilder.incr("my_count_column"))
                        .where(QueryBuilder.eq(...) ); // Primary key clause
cassandraOperations.execute(updateOp);
```